# 11,3 тысяч(и) тысячи гектар(ов, а)

Tags: грамматика

У автора: "Восстановили за год 11,3 тысяч гектаров леса". Считаю, что надо 11,3 тысячи. А вот "гектаров" или "гектара"? Как правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

11 целых и 3 десятых части (чего?) тысячи гектаров